# Launch an application on a remote PC using c#

Tags: c#, lan

I want to launch an application on remote computer that is connected via LAN.

This is the code that I have used:

```
string sLogin = "Administrator";
string sPassword = "Password";
string sComputer = "192.168.201.224";

ManagementScope ms;
ConnectionOptions co = new ConnectionOptions();
co.Username = sLogin;
co.Password = sPassword;
co.EnablePrivileges = true;
co.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

ms = new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\CIMV2", sComputer), co);

ms.Connect();

ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");
System.Management.ManagementClass classObj = new System.Management.ManagementClass(ms, path, null);
System.Management.ManagementBaseObject inParams = null;
inParams = classObj.GetMethodParameters("Create");
inParams["CommandLine"] = "notepad.exe";
inParams["CurrentDirectory"] = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\";
ManagementBaseObject outParams = classObj.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
```

The trouble with this is that the Notepad.exe process has started and I can see this process in Task Manager but there is no notepad window.

Could someone suggest what I have done wrong or am missing with this?

And I tried to use method from duplicate. And tried to add authorization.

```
var serverName = "192.168.201.224";
        var psss = "Password";
        try
        {
            System.Security.SecureString str = new System.Security.SecureString();
            for(int i=0; i<psss.Length;i++)
            {
                str.AppendChar(psss[i]);
            }
            //Start the process
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\PsTools");
            info.Domain = "192.168.201.224";
            info.UserName = "Administrator";
            info.Password = str;
            info.FileName = @"C:\PsTools\psexec.exe";
            info.Arguments = @"\\" + serverName + @" -i C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe";
            info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            Process p = Process.Start(info);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

I've got Invalid UserName or Password Exceprion instead of FileNotFound.

P.S.
I've found solution! If it's interesting for someone it's there:

```
var serverName = "192.168.201.224";
        var psss = "Password";
        var user = "Administrator";
        var appPath = @"Path to destination app with cmd line args";
        try
        {

            //Start the process
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            info.FileName = @"C:\PsTools\psexec.exe";
            var args = String.Format(@"\\{0} -d -u {1} -p {2} -i {3} ", serverName,user,psss,appPath);
            info.Arguments = args;

            info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            Process p = Process.Start(info);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

But there are some extra requirements:
You need to switch on LanmanServer on remote PC and share ADMIN$ or C$

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, nice question; I hope you can find some help with this.

Comment: Hi! I hope so..

Comment: @ИванКозлов are logged in as Administrator when check if Notepad.exe is started?

Comment: Not sure that pointed duplicate is real answer for this, what if exactly this approach is required to run app remotely

Comment: @Alexey, Yes I logged as Administrator on computer where I trying to launch notepad

Comment: @Alexey I understand your point, but the bottom line of every duplicate I have seen is it is not possible the WMI way. It is with Remote Powershell.

Comment: @PatrickHofman ok, now it looks more clear.

Comment: @ИванКозлов there is a possibility to pass credentials, please check doc for it, I think it will not be a problem. And what can be a problem it's that you have to modify registry on remote PC by this `reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`

Comment: @Alexey are there any posibilities to use the first method, or it's will be better to leave it and focus at `ProcessStartInfo` method?

Comment: @ИванКозлов to be honest I've never used `ManagementScope` before, can't say for sure. Patrick says - use `psexec`, I think he knows what he is saying